# Accrued Interest on a bond

Tags: bond, accrued-interest

If I were to price a bond on one of its coupon payment days, does that day's coupon payment gets added to the cashflows, if so, do we just discount that by 1 (same day)? ie, C1*df1 + C2*df2 + ... Should C1 be that day's coupon payment, or the next period's coupon payment?

Comment: On coupon dates, accrued interest = 0, and $C_1$ is the next coupon payment.

Comment: That's right. On the coupon date a new coupon cycle begins. The next coupon is (say) 182 days away. Zero days have elapsed in the current (new) coupon cycle and therefore the accrued is 0*coupon/182 = 0.

Comment: That coupon hits your cash account. It is gone from the bond price.

Answer (score 1):

There is the concept of **ex-div** on stocks and bonds. This is short for ex-dividend (or ex-coupon). If you transact a bond or a stock on an ex-div date then, as the investor, you will not receive the dividend or the coupon which is imminently due to be paid, usually within a few a days or weeks. Instead, as an investor, the first coupon you will receive is the one **after** that.

This is why you see stock prices fall on ex-div dates since they reflect the value of the different cashflows for investors. It is also apparent in the **dirty price** of bonds, however most bond price charts are **clean prices** and already exclude the accrued interest so this is not noticeable on those charts.